# When in a docker container with wireguard, why can I only access nginx from the docker host and not remotely?

Tags: linux, docker, nginx, networking

I recently forked [horjulf/docker-rutorrent-autodl](https://github.com/horjulf/docker-rutorrent-autodl) to create this [docker image](https://github.com/joe-p/docker-rtorrent-wireguard), which is mostly the same as the upstream image with the exception of wireguard being used within the container.

The image works as intended (torrents are downloaded via wireguard), but for some reason I cannot connect to the web-interface on port 80 from any machine in my LAN other than the machine the container is running on.

**On the machine running docker:**

```
$ curl localhost
<html>
<head><title>401 Authorization Required</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>401 Authorization Required</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.16.1</center>
</body>
</html>
```

**On another machine:**

```
$ curl -m 10 192.168.1.204
curl: (28) Connection timed out after 10001 milliseconds
```

If I run tcpdump in the container, I can see traffic in both instances, but nginx is only picking up connections from the docker host.

**curl from docker host:**

```
# tcpdump -ni any port 80
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked v1), capture size 262144 bytes
22:31:43.040840 IP 172.17.0.1.50186 > 172.17.0.2.80: Flags [S], seq 738211264, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2453598083 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
22:31:43.040899 IP 172.17.0.2.80 > 172.17.0.1.50186: Flags [S.], seq 3143048017, ack 738211265, win 65160, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 4217255749 ecr 2453598083,nop,wscale 7], length 0
22:31:43.040950 IP 172.17.0.1.50186 > 172.17.0.2.80: Flags [.], ack 1, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 2453598083 ecr 4217255749], length 0
22:31:43.041065 IP 172.17.0.1.50186 > 172.17.0.2.80: Flags [P.], seq 1:74, ack 1, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 2453598083 ecr 4217255749], length 73: HTTP: GET / HTTP/1.1
22:31:43.041080 IP 172.17.0.2.80 > 172.17.0.1.50186: Flags [.], ack 74, win 509, options [nop,nop,TS val 4217255749 ecr 2453598083], length 0
22:31:43.041135 IP 172.17.0.2.80 > 172.17.0.1.50186: Flags [P.], seq 1:386, ack 74, win 509, options [nop,nop,TS val 4217255749 ecr 2453598083], length 385: HTTP: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
22:31:43.041165 IP 172.17.0.1.50186 > 172.17.0.2.80: Flags [.], ack 386, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 2453598083 ecr 4217255749], length 0
22:31:43.041485 IP 172.17.0.1.50186 > 172.17.0.2.80: Flags [F.], seq 74, ack 386, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 2453598083 ecr 4217255749], length 0
22:31:43.041529 IP 172.17.0.2.80 > 172.17.0.1.50186: Flags [F.], seq 386, ack 75, win 509, options [nop,nop,TS val 4217255749 ecr 2453598083], length 0
22:31:43.041551 IP 172.17.0.1.50186 > 172.17.0.2.80: Flags [.], ack 387, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 2453598083 ecr 4217255749], length 0
22:31:45.731651 IP 203.165.175.240.443 > 172.17.0.2.80: Flags [S], seq 403576734, win 5840, length 0
22:31:45.731749 IP 172.17.0.2.80 > 203.165.175.240.443: Flags [S.], seq 611678211, ack 403576735, win 64860, options [mss 1380], length 0
22:31:46.747487 IP 172.17.0.2.80 > 203.165.175.240.443: Flags [S.], seq 611678211, ack 403576735, win 64860, options [mss 1380], length 0
22:31:47.242837 IP 203.165.175.240.443 > 172.17.0.2.80: Flags [S], seq 944158363, win 5840, length 0
22:31:47.242918 IP 172.17.0.2.80 > 203.165.175.240.443: Flags [.], ack 1, win 64860, length 0
22:31:48.763481 IP 172.17.0.2.80 > 203.165.175.240.443: Flags [S.], seq 611678211, ack 403576735, win 64860, options [mss 1380], length 0
22:31:52.795484 IP 172.17.0.2.80 > 203.165.175.240.443: Flags [S.], seq 611678211, ack 403576735, win 64860, options [mss 1380], length 0
22:32:00.987483 IP 172.17.0.2.80 > 203.165.175.240.443: Flags [S.], seq 611678211, ack 403576735, win 64860, options [mss 1380], length 0
```

**curl from remote machine in LAN:**

```
# tcpdump -ni any port 80
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked v1), capture size 262144 bytes
22:33:39.077808 IP 192.168.1.205.59908 > 172.17.0.2.80: Flags [S], seq 648471846, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 614310621 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
22:33:39.077904 IP 172.17.0.2.80 > 192.168.1.205.59908: Flags [S.], seq 3326921658, ack 648471847, win 64296, options [mss 1380,sackOK,TS val 3369843603 ecr 614310621,nop,wscale 7], length 0
22:33:39.291489 IP 172.17.0.2.80 > 192.168.1.205.59906: Flags [S.], seq 1487907720, ack 4159358623, win 64296, options [mss 1380,sackOK,TS val 3369843816 ecr 614302742,nop,wscale 7], length 0
22:33:40.084398 IP 192.168.1.205.59908 > 172.17.0.2.80: Flags [S], seq 648471846, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 614311628 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
22:33:40.084482 IP 172.17.0.2.80 > 192.168.1.205.59908: Flags [S.], seq 3326921658, ack 648471847, win 64296, options [mss 1380,sackOK,TS val 3369844609 ecr 614310621,nop,wscale 7], length 0
22:33:41.115483 IP 172.17.0.2.80 > 192.168.1.205.59908: Flags [S.], seq 3326921658, ack 648471847, win 64296, options [mss 1380,sackOK,TS val 3369845640 ecr 614310621,nop,wscale 7], length 0
22:33:42.100132 IP 192.168.1.205.59908 > 172.17.0.2.80: Flags [S], seq 648471846, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 614313644 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
22:33:42.100220 IP 172.17.0.2.80 > 192.168.1.205.59908: Flags [S.], seq 3326921658, ack 648471847, win 64296, options [mss 1380,sackOK,TS val 3369846625 ecr 614310621,nop,wscale 7], length 0
22:33:44.123484 IP 172.17.0.2.80 > 192.168.1.205.59908: Flags [S.], seq 3326921658, ack 648471847, win 64296, options [mss 1380,sackOK,TS val 3369848648 ecr 614310621,nop,wscale 7], length 0
22:33:46.324156 IP 192.168.1.205.59908 > 172.17.0.2.80: Flags [S], seq 648471846, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 614317868 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
22:33:46.324239 IP 172.17.0.2.80 > 192.168.1.205.59908: Flags [S.], seq 3326921658, ack 648471847, win 64296, options [mss 1380,sackOK,TS val 3369850849 ecr 614310621,nop,wscale 7], length 0
22:33:47.483487 IP 172.17.0.2.80 > 192.168.1.205.59906: Flags [S.], seq 1487907720, ack 4159358623, win 64296, options [mss 1380,sackOK,TS val 3369852008 ecr 614302742,nop,wscale 7], length 0
22:33:50.555483 IP 172.17.0.2.80 > 192.168.1.205.59908: Flags [S.], seq 3326921658, ack 648471847, win 64296, options [mss 1380,sackOK,TS val 3369855080 ecr 614310621,nop,wscale 7], length 0
22:33:58.747485 IP 172.17.0.2.80 > 192.168.1.205.59908: Flags [S.], seq 3326921658, ack 648471847, win 64296, options [mss 1380,sackOK,TS val 3369863272 ecr 614310621,nop,wscale 7], length 0
22:34:03.611484 IP 172.17.0.2.80 > 192.168.1.205.59906: Flags [S.], seq 1487907720, ack 4159358623, win 64296, options [mss 1380,sackOK,TS val 3369868136 ecr 614302742,nop,wscale 7], length 0
22:34:14.875484 IP 172.17.0.2.80 > 192.168.1.205.59908: Flags [S.], seq 3326921658, ack 648471847, win 64296, options [mss 1380,sackOK,TS val 3369879400 ecr 614310621,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

**nginx access log:**

```
$ cat access.log 
172.17.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:20:58:29 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 401 179 "-" "curl/7.68.0"
172.17.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:21:00:05 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 401 179 "-" "curl/7.68.0"
172.17.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:21:14:25 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 401 179 "-" "curl/7.68.0"
172.17.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:21:17:34 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 401 179 "-" "curl/7.68.0"
172.17.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:21:27:45 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 401 179 "-" "curl/7.68.0"
172.17.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:21:33:49 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 401 179 "-" "curl/7.68.0"
172.17.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:21:42:41 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 401 179 "-" "curl/7.68.0"
172.17.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:21:47:51 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 401 179 "-" "curl/7.68.0"
172.17.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:21:49:44 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 401 179 "-" "curl/7.68.0"
172.17.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:22:02:29 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 401 179 "-" "curl/7.68.0"
172.17.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:22:02:31 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 401 179 "-" "curl/7.68.0"
172.17.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:22:02:33 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 401 179 "-" "curl/7.68.0"
172.17.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:22:02:35 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 401 179 "-" "curl/7.68.0"
172.17.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:22:02:37 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 401 179 "-" "curl/7.68.0"
172.17.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:22:02:39 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 401 179 "-" "curl/7.68.0"
172.17.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:22:02:45 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 401 179 "-" "curl/7.68.0"
172.17.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:22:04:47 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 401 179 "-" "curl/7.68.0"
172.17.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:22:09:05 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 401 179 "-" "curl/7.68.0"
172.17.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020:22:10:24 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 401 179 "-" "curl/7.68.0"
```

**nginx.conf**

```
## Version 2018/08/16 - Changelog: https://github.com/linuxserver/docker-baseimage-alpine-nginx/commits/master/root/defaults/nginx.conf
## Version 2020/08/18 - Added htpasswd support for docker-rtorrent-wireguard
                                                                                                                                                             
user abc;                                   
worker_processes 4;                                                                                     
pid /run/nginx.pid;                                                                                     
include /etc/nginx/modules/*.conf;     
                                                                              
events {                               
        worker_connections 768;             
        # multi_accept on;                                                    
}                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                             
http {                                 
                                                                                                                                                                                   
        ##                                                                    
        # Basic Settings              
        ##                                  
                                       
        sendfile on;                                                                                                                                                                                             
        tcp_nopush on;                      
        tcp_nodelay on;                                                                                                      
        keepalive_timeout 65;                                                            
        types_hash_max_size 2048;      
        # server_tokens off;                                                  
                                                                              
        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;                                                                                                                                                                                                                
        # server_name_in_redirect off;                                                   
                                                                              
        client_max_body_size 0;                     
                                       
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;                                                                                       
        default_type application/octet-stream;                                                          
                                       
        ##                                                                    
        # Logging Settings                                                    
        ##                                                                               
                                                                                         
        access_log /config/log/nginx/access.log;                              
        error_log /config/log/nginx/error.log;                                
                                                                                         
        ##                                                                                              
        # Gzip Settings                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        ##                             
                                       
        gzip on;                                                                                        
        gzip_disable "msie6";                                                            
                                                                                         
        # gzip_vary on;                                                       
        # gzip_proxied any;                                                                                                  
        # gzip_comp_level 6;                                                             
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;                                                            
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;                                                                        
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
                                                                                         
        ##                                                                                              
        # nginx-naxsi config                                                                            
        ##                                  
        # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi                                                                          
        ##                                                                                              
                                                                                         
        #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;
                                                                                                                             
        ##                                                                                                                   
        # nginx-passenger config                                                                                             
        ##                                                                                              
        # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger                                                                      
        ##                                  
                                                                                                                             
        #passenger_root /usr;                       
        #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;              
                                                              
        ##                                                                                                                   
        # Virtual Host Configs                                
        ##                                                                                                                   
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;                                                                                    
        include /config/nginx/site-confs/*;                    
                                                              
        auth_basic "Login Required";                                                                                         
        auth_basic_user_file /config/nginx/.htpasswd;                                                                        
                                                              
}                                                             
                                                                                                                             
                                                              
#mail {                                                       
#       # See sample authentication script at:                 
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#                                                             
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;                                                                                      
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";                      
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";             
#                                                             
#       server {                                              
#               listen     localhost:110;                      
#               protocol   pop3;                                              
#               proxy      on;                                
#       }                                                                     
#                                                                             
#       server {                                                              
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;                                              
#               proxy      on;                                                
#       }                                                                     
#}                                                                            
daemon off;
```

**/config/nginx/site-confs/default:**

```
upstream backendrtorrent {
    server unix:/run/php/.rtorrent.sock;
}

server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;

    listen 443 ssl;

    root /app/rutorrent;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name _;

    ssl_certificate /config/keys/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /config/keys/cert.key;

    client_max_body_size 0;

    location / {
        location ~ .php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }
    }

    location /RPC2 {
        access_log /config/log/nginx/rutorrent.rpc2.access.log;
        error_log /config/log/nginx/rutorrent.rpc2.error.log;
        include /etc/nginx/scgi_params;
        scgi_pass backendrtorrent;
    }
}
```

**docker create:**

```
docker create --name=ruvpn \
-v ~/docker/ruvpn/config:/config \
-v /mnt/8tb/torrents:/downloads \
-e PGID=1000 -e PUID=1000 \
-e TZ=America/New_York \
-p 80:80 -p 5000:5000 \
-p 51413:51413 -p 6881:6881/udp \
--cap-add NET_ADMIN \
--sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.src_valid_mark=1 \
joepol/rtorrent-wireguard
```

**docker version:**

```
Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b7f0
```

Running on a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 (server)

Comment: I think its some firewall issue. As you are able to access the url in docker container from the host machine, i think the issue is your other system in the network is unable to connect to host system. look at the firewall, network and sharing options and port forwarding

Comment: @cerofrais I don't believe it's a firewall issue because the other system can connect to the docker host just fine. I can see the remote traffic in my docker container with tcpdump and the upstream image works using the same ports. This means there's some sort of problem between the docker network and nginx, which is likely caused by wireguard.

Comment: @Joe_P did you manage anything with this one? Hitting it myself.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that in your case the `SYN` reaches nginx while the `ACK` gets routed (at least an attempt is made) through the Wireguard tunnel.

In my case I added this to the client Wireguard config:

```ini
[Interface]
... 
PostUp = ip rule add sport 80 lookup main; ip rule add sport 443 lookup main
PostDown = ip rule del sport 80 lookup main; ip rule del sport 443 lookup main

[Peer] 
...
```

and everything started working even with the Wireguard tunnel up.